# How to get the previous value of recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I need to see the previous, current and next value of a function. For example, a simple recursive addition function like this

```
x=1
x_old=1
def rec(x, x_old):
    a=2
    x_old=x-a
    print('old: ', x_old)
    print('current: ', x)
    x=x+a
    print('new: ', x, '\n')
    rec(x, x_old)
    
rec(x, x_old)
```

but the real task does not involve addition or subtraction, so the only way to determine is to remember it from a previous iteration. How can this be done?

My code which is not working:

```
x=1
x_old=1
def rec(x, x_old):
    print('old: ', x_old)
    print('current: ', x)
    x={some complex function that changes x}
    print('new: ', x, '\n')
    rec(x, x_old)
    x_old=x

    
rec(x, x_old)
```

Comment: try moving the recursive call `rec(x, x_old)` inside the function to after the line where you give x_old a new value `x_old=x`

Comment: switch `rec(x, x_old)` and `x_old=x`

Comment: you can try to apply a _memoization_ decoration

Answer (score 4):

You can pass x_new and x_curr into your recursive calls, which will give you access to the current and previous values of x. Something like:

```
def rec(x, x_old):
    print('old: ', x_old)
    print('current: ', x)
    x_new = some_complex_function(x)
    print('new: ', x_new, '\n')
    rec(x_new, x)
x = 1
x_old = None
rec(x, x_old)
```